# VB.NET: Convert Dictionary With Custom Type To Object

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, object, converters, designer

I have A Property in My own Custom Component with This Dictionary Type: ** Dictionary(Of Integer, RegistryDataItem) **

When I use that at designer Show this message at ErrorList:

> Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,StringProvider.RegistryDataItem]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,StringProvider.RegistryDataItem]'.

How can I Correct this Problem and Make an Object Converter for my Dictionary?!

```
   Protected RegistryDatasValue As New Dictionary(Of Integer, RegistryDataItem)
    <ProviderType(ProvideTypes.RegistryData)>
    <Browsable(True), RefreshProperties(RefreshProperties.All)>
    <Editor(GetType(StringTableCollectionEditor), GetType(Drawing.Design.UITypeEditor))>
    <DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)>
    Public Property RegistryDatas() As Dictionary(Of Integer, RegistryDataItem)
        Get
            Return RegistryDatasValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Dictionary(Of Integer, RegistryDataItem))
            RegistryDatasValue = value
        End Set
    End Property
```

---

```
<Serializable())>
Public Class RegistryDataItem
 ...
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the problem about that Message at ErrorList.

When each time I Build/Rebuild my customized Component that's Assembly Version had changed and My **'RegistryDataItem'** Class was in my own Component so had that Message As A Bug.

1. Project Properties
2. Application Tab.
3. Click on **'Assembly Information'** Button.
4. Fill Assembly Version's Edit Boxes by 0 That one has filled by star(*) or is Empty.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIcyd.png)